# How to read child_process.spawnSync stdout with stdio option 'inherit'

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

```
var childProcess = cp.spawnSync(command, args, {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'inherit',
    encoding: 'utf-8'
});
```

childProcess.output always eq [null, null, null]

process.stdout.write hook doesn't give me any output

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I have the same problem, I need to use `'inherit'` in order to keep the progress display but I cannot hook `stdout.write` or listen for `data` event...

Comment: @FranDios My workaround is to use pipe to catch process output `stdio: [0, isOutputNeeded ? 'pipe' : 1, 2],`

Answer (score 26):

If you don't use `'pipe'` then `childProcess.output` will not contain the output.

```
var cp = require('child_process');

var command = 'echo';
var args = ['hello', 'world'];

var childProcess = cp.spawnSync(command, args, {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env,
    stdio: 'pipe',
    encoding: 'utf-8'
});

console.log(childProcess.output); // [ null, 'hello world\n', '' ]
```

This is sorta kinda indicated in the [documentation for `child.stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout) and elsewhere, but it's not entirely unambiguous. (By all means, if you wish to see it improved, open a pull request against [the Node.js repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node).)

Comment: This way I will miss child_process progress displaying. It's important for me.

Comment: @nitro-n: see to my solution to get in-progress output

Comment: Thanks for this. For others, you can get the output string with `childProcess.output[1] #=> 'hello world\n'`

Answer (score 6):

Use this for in-process displaying of progress:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

var command = 'echo';
var args = ['hello', 'world'];

var childProcess = cp.spawnSync(command, args, {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    env: process.env,
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr],
    encoding: 'utf-8'
});
```

So you replace string `'pipe'` with the array `[process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]`.

Comment: Please comment on down-vote. We are all here to learn and help learning, right?

Comment: My guess is the downvote is due to the fact that this solution does not include a way to read the value of `stdout`. It *does* show how to inspect/display stdout, but I believe @nitro-n was asking for a way to store stdout *and* display it (via `stdio: 'inherit'`).

`stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]` is equivalent to `stdio: 'inherit'`. So, effectively, this solution is the same as the example in the original question.

Comment: `stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]` is equivalent to the OP's `stdio: 'inherit'`.

Comment: Voted up only because this discussion allowed to clarify what it was said by @Bluu